# Tutorial on how to write a custom I/O

Tags: apache-beam

I am unable to use the IOs that are provided with the beam sdk. In my case, data resides in LDAP (or in other enterprise apps). Hence the need to develop custom I/Os. But, I find that there isn't even a single tutorial on how to write an IO. Between trying to figure out how to use AutoValue and how to use PCollection, I am having a tough time (and yes, I can read code on github).

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

[Developing a new I/O connector](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/developing-io-overview/) guide is a good starting point.

If you decide to implement a source using the `Splittable DoFn` framework, there 's more documentation [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#splittable-dofns).